# MariaDb OPTIMIZE TABLE progress jumps from 99% to 0%

Tags: mariadb

I have a very large table that I am normalizing, so a whole range of `url varchar(1024)` fields have been replaced by `url_id bigint(20)` that lookup the url in another table. Now I've dropped the `url` field, and I want to reduce the table size with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

This starts fine, but takes about 2 hours before `show processlist` suggests the progress has reached 99.9 percent. Then the progress suddenly drops to 0 again. The query still displays in `show processlist`, and the duration of the query continues to increase, so I'm sure I'm not looking at a new query.

Is there any way to know whether anything has gone wrong, or will it cycle through this process a few times, and if so, how can I know how many iterations it requires before it will be done?

Comment: Well spotted. Confirmed and [report as a bug MDEV-30533](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30533)

Comment: 3 times it repeats apparently, and its a bug in the progress reporting rather than the process.